# Kitty appears when viewing Schedule tab of chat room info

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message, 500-server-error

I clicked on [a link to a chat page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6697/anime-and-manga?tab=schedule), and it is giving me the kitty ["Oops! Something Bad Happened!"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/info/6697/anime-and-manga).

Happens both logged in and logged out.

The same thing happens with other rooms' Schedule tabs, e.g. on [Mathematics chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics?tab=schedule) and also on [Stack Overflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/22693/assembly?tab=schedule).

Comment: Yeah, seems specific to the schedule tab for all rooms.

Comment: Just so you guys know, I noticed something similar when I was being redirected/logged in and tried to log in at the same time.  Probably some race/concurrency thing in the log-in code that shouldn't ever "need" to be checked but sometimes could be checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was indeed constrained to the "schedule" tabs of the room pages. Fixed now.

Actually it was fixed 17 hours ago, but somehow we never deployed the fix. I've done that now.