# Sites, tags are intermittently devoid of questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, questions, caching

[Super User](http://superuser.com) seems to be erroring intermittently, giving me a blank page of questions, and [David reported something similar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8035856#8035856):

> [image: error]

Subir has reported something similar in Tavern occurring on [English Language Learners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6ypP.jpg) and [Travel Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5GQl.jpg).

I also see the [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag [as empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic):

[image: 0 qs]

On [the FAQ tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic?sort=faq&pagesize=50), it's showing up with 0 total questions and 2 featured questions, which proves it's a bug rather than a burninated tag:

[image: 2 questions]

However, it seems to display fine when logged out.

*(Moved from [Kitty appears when viewing Schedule tab of chat room info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166879/kitty-appears-when-viewing-schedule-tab-of-chat-room-info) since it doesn't seem to be related.)*

Comment: Happening on JLU too.

Comment: @animuson Is it perhaps [related to a deploy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117152/newest-questions-page-no-new-questions-though-they-exist)?

Comment: It got worse. I'm seeing this on all the non-SO sites' front pages now, including metas (http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Troyen: Eh, they probably pushed a change that broke the questions cache. Eventually, all lists on all sites should exhibit the same symptoms of having empty lists as the caches continue to attempt reloading and break.

Comment: And [here on ELU](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Gd4.png).

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to see if I can create a duplicate circle here, and apparently the answer is yes. This post was at 4/5 duplicate of the other post when the other post was closed. Of course I can't cast the last dupe vote since the other question is already closed, but I could cast a "Too Localized" vote, and the result of that (because majority wins) is that now these two questions are closed as duplicates of each other

Comment: @TimYiJiang: WAT

Comment: @TimYiJiang: TIME FOR A META POST!!! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was transient during the migration between data centers.